# How to measure execution time of a particular block of code in Cloud Function for Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I wanted to measure the execution time of a particular block of code running on google cloud function( for firebase write event). Can anyone tell me how to do it.

Is there no specific tool to measure the execution time.

**I have coded 2 codes. So, I wanted to know which code will have better execution time which in turn gives better performance.**

I tried to use process.hrtime() in the following code but it yields different results for same data.

*Algo 1 Running time 299661890

Algo 1 Running time 5684236

Algo 1 Running time 10185061*

*start time [ 87, 594147806 ]
'Algo 1 Running time 9251749'*

*start time [ 22, 803098325 ]
'Algo 1 Running time 1498176261'*

```
// Import the Firebase SDK for Google Cloud Functions.
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var t0
var mymap= new Map();
    exports.processData=functions.database.ref("/test").onWrite(event=>{
    const dataValue = event.data.child('data').val()
    dataValue.body = myFuction(dataValue.body)
    const promise = event.data.ref.child('data').set(dataValue)
  '
    //Finish Time
    t1=process.hrtime(t0)

    var RunTime=Math.round((t1[0]*1000000000) + (t1[1]));
    console.log("Algo 1 Running time "+RunTime)
    return promise;
    }
})

function myFunction(s){
    // start time 
    t0=process.hrtime()
    var newValue=0
    myProbdict.forEach(mapElements);
    function mapElements(value, key, map) {
        if(newValue< 68){
        reduction+=parseInt(value)
        var regexstring ="\\b"+`${key}`+"\\b"
        var regexp = new RegExp(regexstring, "gi");
        s= s.replace(regexp,"#")
        }
    }
    return dataValue
}
```

Comment: Can you share what ` process.hrtime() ` yields?

Comment: console log :
Algo 1 Running time 299661890
Algo 1 Running time 5684236
Algo 1 Running time 10185061

Comment: It's better if you edit your main post so that every one can see them immediately. As I understand the difference between first and the second run is 52 or so. Right?

Comment: @A.Queue
I could not be able to figure out any specific pattern of the runs as it sometimes increases and some time decreases.
For better understanding, I had made the edit to the Question.So you can go through it

Answer (score 2):

No need to do any thing complex like the other answers!

You can simply do this:

```js
console.time(`time spent on complex thing`)

await doSomethingComplex()

console.timeEnd(`time spent on complex thing`)
```

And then you will see it in the Google Cloud Console > Cloud Functions > select your function > Click "LOGS"

Here is an example of how it will look:
[image]

Please note:
The string you put into `console.time` needs to be the same as the one in `console.timeEnd` for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect to have a constant execution time. The time it takes to execute a function is always different because it depends on the current network status (and probably the current server usage as well).

I found a good example in [this blog post](https://blog.tompawlak.org/measure-execution-time-nodejs-javascript). The blog writer wrote a function that is supposed to be executed in 1ms:

```
var start = new Date();
var hrstart = process.hrtime();

    setTimeout(function (argument) {
        // execution time simulated with setTimeout function
        var end = new Date() - start,
            hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);

        console.info("Execution time: %dms", end);
        console.info("Execution time (hr): %ds %dms", hrend[0], hrend[1]/1000000);
}, 1);
```

On the first execution, he got the expected result:

```
Execution time: 1ms
Execution time (hr): 0s 1.025075ms
```

But on the second execution, the function took a little more than 1ms:

```
Execution time: 3ms
Execution time (hr): 0s 2.875302ms
```

If you need to know the execution time of your code block, you can take these outputs and calculate the average: (29961890+5684236+10185061)÷3 which would result in something like 15277062.

Comment: Better gather more outputs . Gather a few hundreds measurements for both implementations, then calculate mean and standard deviation. Look at ["Basic Benchmarking Statistics"](http://beza1e1.tuxen.de/articles/basic_benchmark_statistics.html)